# Is there any keyboard shortcut to turn on and off shuffle and turn on repeating on iTunes?

Tags: itunes, keyboard

Is there any keyboard shortcut to turn on and off shuffle and turn on repeating on iTunes? They aren't mentioned on iTunes help section Keyboard Shortcut.

Answer (score 3):

1. find repeat and shuffle in iTunes menus and memorize their name as is.
2. Press <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>, Type `Keyboard` and press <kbd>enter</kbd>.
3. select <kbd>Keyboard Shortcuts</kbd>
4. in left side of the page, find `Application Shortcuts` and select it.
5. click <kbd>+</kbd> button below
6. in front of `Application`, choose iTunes
7. type the exact name of the menu item for shuffle and repeat
8. set shortcut keys for them.

Comment: Where is spotlight located (thing you mention on 2)? I'm beginner so please be patient.

Comment: Press Command(The key that looks like the logo of this website) + Space, or you can find it in the top right of the screen(the magnifier icon)

Comment: Sorry I forget to tell this: I'm in Windows 7. Not Mac OS. Then i can find the magnifier icon, but after type `Keyboard`, I don't see `Keyboard Shortcuts`.

Comment: I don't think the short key assignment would work in Win7, but in Mac when you type keyboard the top hit would lead you to a setting screen which has a button named `Keyboard shortcuts`

Comment: by the way, in win7 does iTunes have a menu? if so, see if they already have a short key. (it should be written in front of their names in their menu items)

Comment: For iTunes 11: I added two keyboard shortcuts, namely CMD + SHIFT + S for "Turn On Shuffle" and CMD + SHIFT + S for "Turn Off Shuffle". Works like a charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

For nested Menu options like this one shown in the image below:

[image: Nested Menu Option]

A shortcut can be added by specifying the Menu Item name as:
**Controls->Repeat->One**

For some older versions of OSX, this works:
**>Controls>Repeat>One**

You can see it solves the problem of two different nested menu items having the exact same name. Cause the full path will always be different.

Answer (score 2):

iTunes 12 has broken the original Keyboard pane fix. Now Shuffle is a dropdown with two options unhelpfully named *On* and *Off*.

**The following steps work for the current version of iTunes (v12):**

1. Open the **Keyboard** preferences pane in the System Preferences App.
2. Go to the **Shortcuts** tab
3. Click on **App Shortcuts** in the left sidebar
4. Click the **plus icon** below the list on the right
5. Select **iTunes** from the Application dropdown
6. Type the word **On** into the Menu Title box.
7. Click on the **Keyboard Shortcut** box and press the key combination you want to use to turn shuffle on. I use <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.
8. Click **Add**.
9. Repeat steps 4-7 for turning shuffle off, but this time use **Off** as the Menu Title and ***choose a different keyboard shortcut*** for it. I use <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> for turning shuffle off.

Comment: Note that "Off" is not a unique menu action anymore; Repeat is a dropdown with "Off", "All", and "One" as options. The steps above happen to work for turning shuffle off, but only because that's considered the first item named "Off". These steps don't work for creating a shortcut to turn off repeat.

Comment: Is there a workaround for turning off repeat? This is such arcane magic; are the incantations documented anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer for fellow Win 7 users: type the sequence <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to toggle Shuffle. (A little harder to remember than your basic shortcut, but it does the job. You'll just be selecting each menu in turn.)